# Erro de compilação SFML no Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Preciso fazer um jogo para uma matéria da faculdade utilizando a biblioteca SFML e a linguagem C++. Segui esse [tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php) para configurar o Code::blocks, e colei o seguinte arquivo de teste indicado no tutorial:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Porém, ao compilar, a seguinte mensagem fica no build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in sfml-15-05 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Linking stage skipped (build target has no object files to link)
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
```

E quando clico em executar, aparece uma caixa de texto dizendo `It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?`. Clicando em Sim, a janela abre novamente. Clicando em não, aparece uma tela de console dizendo `Process returned 4256912 (0x40F490) executin time : -0.000 s Press any key to continue.`

O esperado no tutorial é que apareça uma janela com um circulo verde.

Já pesquisei estes erros mas não consegui resolver.